# What devices are used in a proton accelerator to separate the protons from their electrons and send the protons into the vacuum chamber?

Tags: protons, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

I understand the general idea of how they accelerate the protons once they get them isolated in the chamber, but what's the device they use to isolate them to begin with even called?

Comment: Well, the ion source is biased at a positive voltage with respect to the beam line, so only the protons want to leave - the electrons are attracted back to the source.

Comment: The system that does that is called the "injector". I not an expert and the little that I know about injectors is skewed heavily toward electron injectors.